# Can't get the value of ''i'' on the second ''FOR''

Tags: c, cs50

I didn't understand how I get on the second for's condition `(altura - i + 1)`.

I didn't get which value i assumes when `altura = 2` for example and then it runs: `for(espaço=3; espaço<=(altura-i+1);espaço++)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int altura;
    int espaço;
    int asterisco;

    do { 
        altura = get_int("Height:");
    } while(altura<1||altura>8);

    for( int i = 0; i<altura;i++)
    {
        for(espaço=3; espaço<=(altura-i+1);espaço++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (asterisco=0;asterisco<=i;asterisco++)
        {
             printf("#");  
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `height` in this code. Does "altura" translate to "height"?

Comment: Yes sorry height=altura

Comment: Might help if you explain what it's supposed to do.

Comment: It's supposed to built a half pyramide of mario's game

Comment: *"which value i assumes"* First it assumes `0`, then it assumes `1`.

Comment: for(espaço=3; espaço<=(altura-i+1);espaço++), when altura=2 which is the value of i?

Comment: If you added a print statement like: `printf("i: %d, espaco: %d\n", i, espaco);` inside your 2nd loop, you'd see the answer to your question when you run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you are familiar with the `for` loops in c.

The for statement has three parts + *code*:

```
for(A;B;C)
{
    *code*;
}
```

Those parts are

- A: initialization statement
- B: test condition
- C: update statement

A is executed only once at the very beginning, and then B, *code* and C are executed in that order until B is false (or the execution of the for is terminated from a statement in *code*).

This means that in your case, for the case of `altura=5` for example,

```
int espaço;
int altura = 5;
for(int i=0; i<altura; i++)
{
        for(espaço=3; espaço<=(altura-i+1); espaço++)
        {
            *code*;
        }

}
```

The outer loop is executed for i=0,1,2,3,4
and in the inner loop,

- when i=0, altura-0+1=6, then espaço=3,4,5
- when i=1, altura-1+1=5, then espaço=3,4
- when i=2, altura-2+1=4, then espaço=3
- when i=3, altura-3+1=3, then the inner loop never executes because espaço=3 but the test condition is espaço < 3
- when i=4, altura-4+1=2, then the inner loop never executes, same as above

Hope it helps

Comment: Thx man it really makes  me understand the ''for'' loop, what I didn't get before was that I thought the  ''i ''value would not change inside the second ''for'' loop  even after the outer for executes ^_^

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Feel free to accept and/or vote the answer ;)